# creating list of objects with names from a list

Tags: r, bizdays

hopefully it is not a duplicate, rather difficult to phrase it correctly (relatively new to R)
So the problem is: I want to use sequences of dates excluding certain weekdays based on the row information. I can use `bizdays` and create `calendar` objects on the fly but it is quite inefficient - I would rather have them created  before and use as needed. On the other side I do not want to create a calendar for every single object that can happen to occur (too many to bother, combination of all weekdays plus versions with/without holidays).

I can create a dataframe with list of dates between start/end date for every row, but i need to provide a calendar with weekdays

```
P <- setDT(R)[, list(ID=ID,  
                     dt=bizseq(Start.Date,End.Date, cal)
), by=1:nrow(R)]
```

To provide a calendar I have to define it like

```
cal <- Calendar(weekdays=c("monday", "tuesday"))
```

now a working dataset that could explain what i am struggling with

```
> M <-c(0,1,1,0)
> T <- c(1,1,1,0)
> W <- c(0,0,0,1)
> df <- data.frame(M,T,W)
> df$S <-paste0("c",df$M,df$T,df$W)
> udf <- unique(df)
> udf
  M T W    S
1 0 1 0 c010
2 1 1 0 c110
4 0 0 1 c001
```

using udf i would like to create a list of calendar objects that i can afterwards pass to the `bizseq` using `get(df$S)`, something along the lines of

```
require(bizdays)

loop or apply?
.... <- Calendar(weekdays=c(ifelse(udf$M==0,"","monday"), ifelse(udf$T==0,"","tuesday"),ifelse(udf$W==0,"","wednesday")))
```

So now the right questions;) Firstly - is it the best approach? then if so - how to create these 3 objects under their names ("`c101`" etc), so for example the `c100` will match the calendar with Monday on - it is not a question how to create a calendar as the method above works (it is enough to substitute the dots with the name), but how to create object `c101` that would become a calendar if i create names in a dynamic way? I could imagine looping through the rows, but have no idea how to force the resulting object to be named `udf$S`. Unless you reckon there is any better method of providing the corresponding calendar than `get()` from a list of pre-created objects (for a dataframe with thousands of dates and combination of days off).
I would like basically to end up with 3 calendar objects named `c010, c110, c001,` but if the expanded table has more unique options to create all other combinations before i run the `setDT()` function

Afterthought: I can add ID to the udf and call the calendars by index and then return the index to df, but I wonder if it is possible to create dynamic names of objects just as I tried

NOTE
following Sathish's lead I used what seems sufficient:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(udf)) {
  cal <- Calendar(weekdays=c(ifelse(udf[i,1]==0,"","monday"), ifelse(udf[i,2]==0,"","tuesday"),ifelse(udf[i,3]==0,"","wednesday")))
  assign(udf[i,4], cal)
}
```

Comment: apply( udf, 1, function(x)  Calendar(weekdays = rep ( x, c( "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday" )))

Comment: No need to create S column in udf

Comment: Are you looking for this or something different?

Comment: yes, it is not matter of applying anything to short udf, but rather using udf to create set of calendars that can be applied to far bigger df. udf is only a list of calendars that have to be precreated - all variants that might be possible). The problem is how would i call the calendar created on udf from the other table

Comment: Please provide the other table. You could use dput to get the data

Comment: the other table is df - imagine it being 65000 rows with date start and date end plus all rules per row if monday is off or not etc. As i mentioned in the afterthough I will probably create an empty list, create all calendars by indexed rows from udf, bind them to the list and call by indexes

Comment: If it is a large table, you could use dput(head( df, 20 ) )

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example, then people can easily understand and help you out with the issue.

Comment: Also show what will be the expected output

Comment: Sathish, the example is reproducible - to answer the question you really need just udf - how to create 3 calendar objects from it using the name that is in udf$S. All other things are irrelevant

Comment: To understand you, show a sample of how the calendar object look like. Please do not mistake me for more questions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135471/discussion-between-slav-and-sathish).

Comment: see if you are looking for this https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html